# Problem with cycle multiplication:

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles

From the rules of the cycle multiplication I know I can do this: $(123)(145)=(231)(145)=(23145)$. However, if I try to solve the following I get repeated elements (the $1$):

$$(126)(123)(145)=(126)(23145)=(612)(23145)=(6123145)$$

Is there a rule I am forgetting here? (I already know how to do it manually, but I want to do it using rules of cycle multiplication). The answer should be $(1456)(23)$

Comment: Before anything else, we should confirm which order you do your multiplications... right to left or left to right.  That is to say, if $\pi,\sigma$ are permutations do you have $(\pi \sigma)(x)=\pi(\sigma(x))$?  Or do you have $(\pi\sigma)(x)=\sigma(\pi(x))$?  It is common that questions like this are all just because the asker was taught to perform multiplications in one direction while whatever calculator or book they are checking against performs them in the other direction.  Both conventions are in common use.

Comment: Concatenating cycles together like you're doing works only if the cycles share only one of their elements (and you are using the right-to-left multiplication convention). If they share more elements, then you'll have to follow what each element does individually as explained in Ethan Bolker's answer. The result is not always a single cycle.

Comment: @JMoravitz I was doing the right to left convention.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis thanks! I did not know I could not use that rule with more elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right to question your final answer. I have no idea why you ended up with repeated $1$s.

You are not missing a rule. You may not understand the rules, or you may have made a mistake.

You are multiplying right to left (which is one convention).

In the product
$$
(612)(23145)
$$
$$
3 \to 1 \to 2
$$
where your calculation has $3 \to 1$. So the correct answer should have the sequence $32$ in one of the cycles, and that should be the only cycle containing a $2$ or a $3$.

What you say the answer should be is not in final form since the cycles are not disjoint.

There is no need to rearrange $(126)$ as $(621)$. All that does is introduce another place where you might make a copying error. Just track what happens to each number, one at a time, right to left.  You can even do that with the original product of three permutations - no need to group two of them first.

Comment: Thanks! I corrected my solution. Also, it was pointed out in the comments that I cannot use the rule multiplication if cycles share more than 1 element. So, as you say, I just have to doit one at a time

Answer (score 1):

Rotate the $5$-cycle again to align the $1$.

$$(612)(23145)\to(6123145)\to(6114523)\to(614523)\to(6145)(23)$$